# Get SNMP monitoring metrics to Ganglia

Tags: monitoring, snmp, ganglia

I have a cluster of servers monitored with ganglia and I just added a new application on one of them. The new application uses an SNMP handler to report about its activity.
I never used SNMP before and would like to gather most of SNMP metrics that I see in the MIB file to my rrd files used by Ganglia.
Would this be possible ?

I wanted to write a new ganglia module that would take into account the new metrics from the new application. So I tried to read the code of the SNMP handler of the application but cannot catch where it takes its information from.
What would be a good way to figure out this situation ?

Thank you!